# Multiple awaits in async try/catch. How do I make one conditional?

Tags: javascript

I have a try/catch function that has multiple await functions that return responses:

```
const { data: { req1 } } = await this.props.submitMember(payload1)
const { data: { req2 } } = await this.props.submitSomething(payload2)
const { data: { req3 } } = await this.props.submitThing(payload3)

if (!req.success || !req2.success || !req3.success) {
  return addNotification('Something went wrong.')
}
```

how do I make one conditional? eg:

```
const { data: { req1 } } = await this.props.submitMember(payload1)
const { data: { req2 } } = await this.props.submitMember(payload2) // IF SOME VARIABLE IS TRUE, DO NOT RUN THIS REQUEST
const { data: { req3 } } = await this.props.submitMember(payload3)

if (!req.success || !req2.success || !req3.success) {
  return addNotification('Something went wrong.')
}
```

Comment: are those request independent from each other? do you want to simplify code or control if request(s) are sent? does `req.success` check mean that your `submitMember` does not reject on failure but always succeeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put one under a conditional clause:

```js
const { data: { req1 } } = await this.props.submitMember(payload1);

const { data: { req2 } } =  mustCheck
 ? await this.props.submitMember(payload2)
 : { data: { req2: { success: true } } } // Did not run, did not fail.
;

const { data: { req3 } } = await this.props.submitMember(payload3);

if (!req.success || !req2.success || !req3.success) {
  return addNotification('Something went wrong.')
}
```

You will have to test `mustCheck` when accessing the result of `req2`, because it legitimately may be undefined if you did not run the request.